# Consuming Value from API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC and has trying to develop a money exchange which has a text box and two drop lists of the currencies to exchange. I used the API web service that has a table holds the currencies names, country and values. My problem is to calculate the value from the API once the user post the action method after inserting the amount in the ConversionRate as I always get a 0 value! What am I doing wrong here?

Index Action method

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Currencies cur)
        {
            if (cur.ConversionRate.Equals(null))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please enter a numeric value");
            }

            if (cur.FromCurrencyId == cur.ToCurrencyId)
            {
                //do something if same currecnies and return.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Can't make the conversion for the same curreny");
            }
            else
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    CurrenciesClient Cur = new CurrenciesClient();
                    var listCurrency = Cur.findAll().ToList();

                    Currencies model = new Currencies();
                    model.FromCurrencies = new SelectList(listCurrency,"FromCurrencyId", "CurrencyName","Value");
                    model.ToCurrencies = new SelectList(listCurrency, "ToCurrencyId", "CurrencyName","Value" );

                    ViewBag.TheResult = listCurrency.Where(c => c.FromCurrencyId == cur.FromCurrencyId && c.ToCurrencyId == cur.ToCurrencyId).FirstOrDefault().ConversionRate * cur.Value;

                    return PartialView("_CurrencyValue");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

API web service CurrenciesClient

```
public class CurrenciesClient 
    {
        private string base_Url = "http://localhost:51646/api/";

        public IEnumerable<Currencies> findAll()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(base_Url);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("currencies").Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var resposeData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var Currency = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Currencies>>(resposeData);
                    return Currency;
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Currencies VM

```
  public class Currencies
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " message")]
        public int FromCurrencyId { get; set; }
        public SelectList FromCurrencies { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ToCurrencyId { get; set; }
        public SelectList ToCurrencies { get; set; }

        public string CurrencyName { get; set; }

        public string CurrencyCountry { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter a numeric value")]
        public decimal ConversionRate { get; set; }  

        public decimal Value { get; set; }

        public SelectList AvailableCurrencies { get; set; }
    }
```

Index View

```
@model Project.ViewModels.Currencies

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div id="ConversionSection">

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "ConversionSection" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConversionRate, new { @class = "form-control" })

            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FromCurrencyId, Model.FromCurrencies as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ToCurrencyId, Model.ToCurrencies as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ToCurrencyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Convert</button>
        }

</div>
@section scripts{
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: difficult to tell. Have you set some breakpoints so you can check the values being posted from the page, and the values being returned by the API, so that you can see if something is null or 0 somewhere unexpectedly?

Comment: Yes, I did set the breaking point and the most confusing part was all the API returns the Count of the Currencies i.e. based on the Ids except the Value which is always a 0!!

Comment: the API returns a list of all currencies. You then select the first item from the list which matches your from/to currencies, and select the ConversionRate property from that first item. Assuming that's actually your intention, you need to check whether ConversionRate is populated correctly, and also whether cur.Value is populated correctly. I can't see where either a count or a "Value" property comes into this?

Comment: P.S. Why don't you let the API filter the currencies for you? Returning all of them and _then_ filtering them seems a bit inefficient. The whole point of an API is that it does some business logic for you.

Comment: P.P.S. Semantically, it feels like the list the API returns is not in fact a list of currencies, but a list of conversion rates between currencies. Each object does not describe a currency, in fact it contains the IDs of two currencies, and a rate of conversion between them. Perhaps this is a misnomer which could be clarified in your design.

Comment: My intention is to select from the list,sent from the API, a currency for a conversion. The user inputs the amount in the text box i.e. ConversionRate. Once press the convert  button the partial view will display the result. How do I filter the list of currencies, I've never used the API before!  I return the IDS, CurrencyNames from the API Currencies table, but the the value isn't there!

Comment: huh? What i mean is send the two currencies selected by the user to the API, have it find the right conversion rate and return an object containing the current conversion rate for those two currencies. Then use that conversion rate to calculate the amount. All I'm saying is transfer the business logic for finding the right conversion rate into your API not your controller. It's just a design idea.

Comment: Anyway to solve your original question, in your Index view you have a textbox for ConversionRate. You don't want the user to enter the conversion rate - this is what the API is finding for you. You want the user to enter the _amount of currency_ they want to convert. I'm guessing this is probably "Value" in your viewmodel?

Comment: I got you now! It seems logical what you said. Yes, I want the user to insert any random amount of currency they want to convert, then the controller process the conversion based on that amount and the rate of the currencies. How do you achieve this? Do I need to change the ConversionRate in the View?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131035/discussion-between-dodi82-and-adyson).

Answer (score 0):

You are allowing the user to enter the Conversion Rate in the form, but then also looking this up in the API. This is not logical. You don't want the user to enter the Conversion Rate themselves - this is the data you are keeping in order to calculate the exchange.

What you aren't getting the user to enter is the amount of currency they want to exchange. This is held in the "Value" field in your ViewModel. Since this is not entered, it's always defaulting to 0, and this is why when you do `ConversionRate * cur.Value` it always returns 0. (The ConversionRate in that equation is, correctly, the one returned by the API, not the one entered by the user).

To solve, simply change

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConversionRate, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Value, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Your UI should probably also contain a label telling the user what to enter!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131075/discussion-on-answer-by-adyson-consuming-value-from-api).